# Recursively make hash for every object in self

Tags: python

```
def __hash__(self):
    """Creating hash for item"""
    if isinstance(self.get_values(), (tuple, list)):

        return tuple([self.__hash__() for e in self.get_values()])

    elif not isinstance(self.get_values(), dict):

        return hash(self.get_values())

    new_o = copy.deepcopy(self.get_values())
    for k, v in new_o.items():
        new_o[k] = self.__hash__()
```

I have custom recursive hash function. `Self.get_values()` contains a list of dicts.I want to iterate every object of self and make hash of it. The problem is that then i call `new_o[k] =self.__hash__()` for example,

i want something like `self.__ hash__(v)`, the v could be a list and i want to call my custom hash function.

Instead of this, it calls hash again for whole self and i get recursion error. I can't do like  `new_o[k] = hash(v)`, because it goes for **hash** function of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the list/tuple or over the items, you need to call the hash method on the object of the iteration you keep calling on `self` which the instance on which you call the method

```
[e.__hash__() for e in self.get_values()] # for list/tuple

new_o[k] = v.__hash__() # for k,v
```

To give :

```
def __hash__(self):
    """Creating hash for item"""
    if isinstance(self.get_values(), (tuple, list)):
        return tuple([e.__hash__() for e in self.get_values()])
    elif not isinstance(self.get_values(), dict):
        return hash(self.get_values())

    new_o = copy.deepcopy(self.get_values())
    for k, v in new_o.items():
        if v: # handle empty and None
            new_o[k] = v.__hash__()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem is that if i call new_o[k] = v.__hash__(), it goes for hash function of it's object. For this case, v could be an empty list [], and if i call it, i got TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. My point is, in this case to go call my __hash__ function for v.

Comment: @AlexNikitin I'd better add an `if`, your hash method is an instance method, it's inside a class, you can't call it with something else. Could you confirm your __hash__ method is in a class ?

Comment: yea, it is in a class

Comment: @AlexNikitin so are yo ok ? You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)